# Is there a way to password protect a Confluence page - cloud version?

Tags: agile

Whenever a user tries to access a Confluence page we want to use some kind of password or passcode to add another level of security to the Confluence page. Is it possible - with or without add ins? Any 3rd party app?

Comment: “Search questions” are off-topic. To be on-topic, this question requires more context. Have you read the Confluence documentation? Why has that not answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

Pages can be restricted to specific users. Take a look at:  https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/page-restrictions-139414.html